# Switch off OpenGL viewport clipping

Tags: opengl-es

I want to draw a number of primitives which are pre-clipped and given in window space coordinates. That means that my vertex shader outputs these coordinates as ( x, y, 0, 1 ). The glViewport is set as ( -1, -1, 2, 2 ) which should disable the viewport transform.

The problem is, that viewport clipping in vertex post-processing removes all coordinates where one components lies outside -w, w   (which is w=1) in this case.

Is there a way in OpenGL ES 3 to disable this clipping?

Regards

Comment: No, there isn't any way to disable this clipping. Just set the viewport to the whole window and scale you coordinates in the vertex shader. Sounds a bit wasteful but this is the way it is.

Comment: If you're trying to do this for performance reasons, modern GPU's don't really do clipping explicitly regardless because it adds additional work in many cases. It mostly happens as a side effect of other parts of the rendering pipeline.

Comment: Doesn't OpenGL guarantee this kind of clipping through the standard?

Comment: Besides the main issue, I'd check your use of `glViewport`; on most platforms you're asking that output be at most two pixels in each dimension, and that all but one pixel of it be off screen. `glViewport` takes window coordinates. Though it sounds like that might just be a question typo?